# How can I use process.cwd() within Angular2 Component with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, angular, process, dirname, getcwd

How can I use

```
process.cwd()
```

within Angular2 Component with TypeScript? What do I have to import?

The following in the constructor

```
console.log("Where I am: ", process.cwd());
```

outputs the error:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: process is not defined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

As I could use process.cwd() and __dirname natively in my JavaScript files, I am wondering, why it does not work instantly?

What do I have to import? Is it my addiction to nodeJS? Or my wrong assumptions: what in node works must work everywhere?

Comment: Can you show your import statement for process?

Comment: Dear @JasonGoemaat , if I am not wrong, it was my question: How can I import process? 

Comment: @Vienna `process` is a node.js module it doesn't exist when running in browser.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly my question: What do I have to do, so that it works in the browser :)

Comment: Oh, that's not possible, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare var process: any;
```

Place it before `@Component`;
It won't give you full intellisense but it satisfies the compiler.